# socketcluster.io deployment on stronloop

Tags: strongloop, socketcluster

Is it proper to deploy an app with socketcluster instead of socket.io on strongloop PM, considering the fact that both socketcluster and strongloop have cluster facilities?

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood [strong-pm](https://github.com/strongloop/strong-pm) is using [strong-supervisor](https://github.com/strongloop/strong-supervisor) for process control, which uses the [cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) feature provided by Node core.

The docs for SocketCluster don't make it immediately obvious, but the [socketcluster](https://github.com/SocketCluster/socketcluster) code pretty clearly shows that it uses cluster.

The docs for cluster specifically say that `cluster.fork()` can only be called from the cluster master. Since strong-supervisor works by only running the application in cluster worker processes, the socketcluster framework won't be able to launch workers.

**TL;DR**: no, socketcluster and strong-pm are not compatible because they are using the same clustering feature.